# ¿Cómo ingresar varias cadenas de texto para luego guardarlas en un archivo txt?

Tags: c, string

Necesito ingresar desde el teclado varias cadenas de texto (1 por cada línea) y terminar de ingresar los datos con la palabra "Salida" y luego presionar la tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd> para que luego la función `fprintf( )` escriba todas las cadena en un txt.

Dejo mi código que por ahora solamente permite ingresar una sola cadena de texto ya que, el oprimir la tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd> guarda la cadena en el archivo y requiero poder escribir varias cadenas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char TextoIngresado[19860];

    FILE *archivo;

    archivo = fopen("personal.txt", "a");

    if (archivo == NULL) {
        perror("personal.txt");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Ingrese un texto de no mas de 19860 caracteres de favor:\n");
    fgets(TextoIngresado, sizeof(TextoIngresado), stdin);
    fprintf(archivo, "%s", TextoIngresado);
    fclose(archivo);
    printf("Guardando.......................\n");
    printf("La informacion ha sido guardada con exito en personal.txt:\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C tiene varias estructuras de control repetitivas: `for`, `do` y `while`.

Para este ejercicio usaremos `do bloque while(condicion);`. Aqui el `bloque` de instrucciones se ejecuta primero y luego se prueba la `condicion`. Si la condición se cumple, se repite todo de nuevo.

Para terminar el ingreso el usuario introduce una línea vacia. En este caso, el texto tiene un `\n` como primer caracter.

He reorganizado un poco el código. En particular, el archivo hay que cerrarlo al final, no dentro del bloque:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char TextoIngresado[19860];

    FILE *archivo;

    archivo = fopen("personal.txt", "a");

    if (archivo == NULL) {
        perror("personal.txt");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Ingrese un texto de no mas de 19860 caracteres de favor:\n");
    printf("(Para terminar ingrese linea vacia)\n");
    do {
        fgets(TextoIngresado, sizeof(TextoIngresado), stdin);
        fprintf(archivo, "%s", TextoIngresado);
        printf("Guardando.......................\n");
    } while(TextoIngresado[0] != '\n');
    
    fclose(archivo);
    printf("La informacion ha sido guardada con exito en personal.txt:\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

produce:

```
Ingrese un texto de no mas de 19860 caracteres de favor:
(Para terminar ingrese linea vacia)
linea uno
Guardando.......................
linea dos
Guardando.......................
linea tres
Guardando.......................

Guardando.......................
La informacion ha sido guardada con exito en personal.txt:

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 8s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

y el archivo `personal.txt` queda:

```
candid@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$ more personal.txt 
linea uno
linea dos
linea tres

candid@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$
```

Nota que el archivo tiene cuatro lineas. La última es la misma línea vacía que ingresó el usuario.

Comment: Perfecto, en efecto sabía que debía utilizar un ciclo "do" o  "while" para establecer la condicionante pero aún estoy muy verde en el tema y no sabía como estructurar nada. Agradezco mucho su respuesta buen hombre. Saludos.